# Почему кнопка не выполняет скрипт?

Tags: excel, vba

Создал кнопку в форме ексель, но она не работает, хотя текстовое поле имеет имя Label 2. Пожалуйста подскажите какая проблема
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы кнопку нажимаете прямо в редакторе? )

Comment: Именно. Там такая кнопка сверху есть, зеленый треугольничек, Run называется. Попробуйте нажать ее, и все проблемы должны исправиться.

Comment: Ну, научите сейчас :) Если находимся не в модуле формы, *Run* запускает макрос, в котором в данный момент находится курсор. Если курсор за пределами процедур, откроется окошко, в котором можна выбрать нужный макрос и уже там, в окне, нажать *Run.* Если находимся в модуле  формы, то стартует сама форма, т.е. выполнится процедура активации формы. Как я понимаю, это часть учебного задания, поэтому нужно создать модуль и в нем написать код активации формы.